# How to load assembly into default load context without adding into GAC?

Tags: assembly-loading

I tried to load the assembly in Assembly Resolve event. Also I got the hook up and loaded the assembly in the app domain using Assembly.LoadFrom.

But when I access a method from the assembly in the same app domain I got assembly not found error as below,

```
Could not load file or assembly......
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
```

It tries to load using default load context. Please help me to load the assembly in default load context without putting in GAC.